# How to pass an class property to a .each block nested inside class>method>each in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wonder how I can pass a class property into function located in a .each of a method as below. I have found that I could call the property from the newly created instance but it means the class can't be replicated. Is there a object inheritance friendly way of calling the class property from inside a function located in function > .each > method > class?

```
class ok {
  constructor() {
    this.jojo = "first state";
  }

  myMethod() {
    let rp = require('request-promise-native');
    let cheerio = require('cheerio');
    rp("https://tomydna.com")
      .then(response => {

        let $ = cheerio.load(response);

        $('a').each(function() {
          this.jojo = "second state"; // This does not work
          ok1.jojo = "second state from outside"; // This would work but it is not good because it is related to one instance only. If a new Instance is created the method stops working.
          console.log(ok1.jojo); // will replicate as many times it finds url on the page.
        });


      });

  }

}

ok1 = new ok();
ok1.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `this` object into another variable. You can not use class `ok` `this` object into `.each` function because inside `.each` this represent current immediate object(`.each` function callback), following example may help you

```
class ok {

    constructor() {
        this.jojo = "first state";
    }

    myMethod() {
        let self = this;
        let rp = require('request-promise-native');
        let cheerio = require('cheerio');
        rp("https://tomydna.com")
            .then(response => {

                let $ = cheerio.load(response);

                $('a').each(function () {
                    self.jojo = "second state"; // This will work
                    ok1.jojo = "second state from outside"; // This would work but it is not good because it is related to one instance only. If a new Instance is created the method stops working.
                    console.log(ok1.jojo); // will replicate as many times it finds url on the page.
                });


            });

    }

}

ok1 = new ok();
ok1.myMethod();
```

Comment: You cannot declare variable in the body of a class...

Comment: thanks @adz5A, updated code

Answer (score 0):

In your `.each` callback, you can use an arrow function. Be sure though if you want to have a reference to the cheerio dom node that your callback is of the form `(index, node) => {/* your code */}`.

Answer (score 0):

its just a scope issue. Assign `this` to a local variable and then use it inside your each. eg:

```
  myMethod() {
    let that = this; //local variable
    let rp = require('request-promise-native');
    let cheerio = require('cheerio');
    rp("https://tomydna.com")
      .then(response => {

        let $ = cheerio.load(response);

        $('a').each(function() {
          that.jojo = "second state"; // usage
          console.log(that.jojo); 
        });


      });

  }
```